# How to be able to select a portion of the screen?

Tags: c#, .net

In some screen capture software when you press a key it's possible for the client to select a portion of the screen. How can I implement that in my software written in framework 2.0 .Net?

Here is a image of what I would like to do : http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3782/portionpb9.png you see, I can select a portion of the screen. How can I do that?

I do not want to know how to take a screenshot... any one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it might not be a solution that you could easily copy&paste but this open source project in C# does have the behavior that your application want : http://www.codeplex.com/cropper

You might be able to take a piece of their code into you application. Here is a image from code plex :

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cropper&DownloadId=8026](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cropper&DownloadId=8026)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/screencaptures/article.php/c6139) that captures the screen. You can either only copy the part of the screen that was selected or try to change the code to only capture that part.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want the effect of selecting a portion of the screen.